# Very long time to schedule the downstream task in airflow

Tags: airflow

I am using airflow 1.10.12, but found that downstream task will be scheduler after a long time of its upstream task finish, it is very strange. e.g. Here'e gantt, you can find the the task is scheduled after 1 minute of its upstream task finish, any way I can make it run faster ?

[image: airflow gantt]

Answer (score 0):

I guess this also depends on your executor, bu Airflow provides some tips on improving the speed, see [Airflow FAQ](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html#how-can-my-airflow-dag-run-faster):

> **parallelism**: This variable controls the number of task instances that runs simultaneously across the whole Airflow cluster. User could increase the parallelism variable in the airflow.cfg.
> **concurrency**: The Airflow scheduler will run no more than concurrency task instances for your DAG at any given time. Concurrency is defined in your Airflow DAG. If you do not set the concurrency on your DAG, the scheduler will use the default value from the dag_concurrency entry in your airflow.cfg.
> **task_concurrency**: This variable controls the number of concurrent running task instances across dag_runs per task.
> **max_active_runs**: the Airflow scheduler will run no more than max_active_runs DagRuns of your DAG at a given time. If you do not set the max_active_runs in your DAG, the scheduler will use the default value from the max_active_runs_per_dag entry in your airflow.cfg.
> **pool**: This variable controls the number of concurrent running task instances assigned to the pool.